# Problems when using NASM assembler

Tags: c++, assembly, nasm

I've got the following ASM code:

```
USE32
Start:
jmp Main
    struc st
        .stLong resd 1
        .stWord resw 1
        .stBuffer   resb    32
    endstruc

    mystruc:
    istruc st
        at st.stLong, dd 1
        at st.stWord, dw 1
    iend
Main:
    mov eax, 1
    mov [mystruc+st.stLong], eax
```

I've compiled it using NASM and tried to execute (step by step) the binary generated in the debugging mode of Visual C++ with the code below:

```
unsigned char hexData[50] = {
    0xEB, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA3,
    0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00 
};




__asm{
    lea eax, hexData
    call eax
}
```

The problem is: executing the first instruction (jmp Main) always results in an access violation exception. :( I don't know what's really going on here. Would you please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: try SECTION .text before the Main:

Comment: Does NASM generated relative address jumps? May be it just jumps to some fixed address, which is invalid in embedded code case

Comment: @Lol4t0: I think all Jumps generated are relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory can have different protections, it can be readable, writable or executable. By default data members that defined by you are not executable to avoid code injection or exploit attack in your code. You have 2 options here:

```
// Remember this function at least allocate a page that is usually 4096 byte
// Use GetSystemInfo to get page size.
void* pvExecutableMem = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 50, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
// Resulting page is executable
memcpy( pvExecutableMem, hexData, 50 );
// Now you can execute this page
__asm {
    mov eax, pvExecutableMem
    call eax
}
```

Another approach is to change protection type of `hexData`:

```
DWORD dwOldProt;
VirtualProtect( hexData, sizeof(hexData), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProt );
```

But because `VirtualXXX` functions work on pages and can't handle only 50 bytes of memory, this will change memory protection of other parts of your memory that can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Side-note (I can't add comment..)

```
__asm{
    lea eax, hexData
    call eax
}
```

You dont need inline assembler to call hexData. Maybe it is OK for MSVC x32, but note MSVC x64 does not have inline assembler.

You may use [following approach](http://ideone.com/1J5qbQ) to call code in binary array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Namespace
{
    namespace Aux
    {
        extern "C" unsigned char hexData[]={0xC3};
    }
    extern "C" void hexData();
}

int main()
{
    Namespace::hexData();
    cout << "alive!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In order to fix access violation - follow BigBoss advice. For instance, following code works OK in MSVC x64:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

namespace Namespace
{
    namespace Aux
    {
        extern "C" unsigned char hexData[]={0xC3};
    }
    extern "C" void hexData();
}

int main()
{
    DWORD dwOldProt;
    VirtualProtect( Namespace::Aux::hexData, sizeof(Namespace::Aux::hexData), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProt );
    Namespace::hexData();
    cout << "alive!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using inline assembler is my favorite way to execute such binary code. :) Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I would prefer also to use inline assembler instead, but unfortunatly it is not available everywhere (like in MSVC x64).